# R: Import Path to File - Quick Options?

Tags: r

I have files that I need to import to R that have very long paths and names.  What's the easiest way to get the path of each file typed in to R?

Was hoping that dragging and dropping the file into R might generate the path, but that doesn't appear to do anything.

I'm working on macOS.  Anyone know any tricks?

Comment: In the finder, right click on the file, then press the "option" key. The "copy" option will become "copy as path name". This will put the full path on your clipboard so you can paste into R.

Comment: Use [file.choose()](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/file.choose.html)

Comment: is putting them all in a folder an option?

Comment: MrFlick this is exactly what I needed, thank you.  If you post your response as an Answer I can accept it.

Comment: It's really a dup of this question on the apple site: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2731/how-can-i-copy-the-path-of-a-file-in-finder. There's nothing R specific really about the problem.